# Set proximity requirement for ESRI Collector observations

Tags: web-mapping, gps, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I am trying to create a Collector map that allows field crews to update a "status" attribute for features in a feature class.  What I would like to do is limit the features that can be edited by the field crew to the features within 100 yards of the user's current device location based on GPS.  Is that something that is supported by the Collector app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I don't think so. The collector app is more lightweight but pretty robust.
You maybe able to do it in a map app within the browser, by using geographic query, but not sure whether the map app reads the GPS of the Mobil device